# Update Bokeh figure from multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bokeh

I am using Bokeh server to plot online data going from a sensor. I wrote a `multiprocessing.Process` subclass that reads data from the sensor and then feeds it through a pipe to another subclass that should update a Bokeh figure with the incoming data.

How to make plotting `Process` asynchronously read from the pipe and plot it to Bokeh?

Consider the `Grapher` class, assuming another process already sends data to the `input_pipe`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

from functools import partial

class Grapher(Process):
  def __init__(self, name, input_pipe):
    super(Grapher, self).__init__(name=name, daemon=True)
    self.input_pipe = input_pipe

    self.doc = curdoc()
    self.source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[], value=[])
    self.fig = figure()
    self.fig.line(source=self.source, x='time', y='value')
    self.doc.add_root(self.fig)
    self.session = push_session(self.doc)  # To keep session updated.

  def run(self):
    while True:
      time, value = self.input_pipe.recv()
      self.doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(self.update, time, value))

  @gen.coroutine
  def update(self, time, value):
    self.source.stream(dict(time=[time], value=[value]))
```

Code here is adopted from the [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads) in Bokeh docs. Separately I run `bokeh serve` so that `curdoc()` has something to connect to. From the Bokeh server logs I see that connection is there.

However, the problem seems to be that `update` does not really get executed after the next tick of the `while` loop here. I can check that by adding a logging message inside `update`, which gets never printed out.

If I try to change `add_next_tick_callback` to just `update` call, the function is indeed run, but the session does not plot anything.

What can cause the issue here? Code looks logical, and I cannot find using docs where this approach may fail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `bokeh.client` approach to apps, if you want events to be serviced, and callbacks to be called when they happen, then you have to call the blocking function `session.loop_until_closed()` at the end. That's what keeps the thing that monitors events and calls callbacks, actually staying around, in order to monitor events and call callbacks.

If calling a blocking function is problematic, and you don't want to use a `bokeh serve app.py` style of app, then you can try calling `session.loop_until_closed()` in another thread (not 100% this will work), or start your own Tornado ioloop and piggy back a Bokeh server app on that directly. That technique will be demonstrated better in the upcoming `0.12.4` release, but you may find this notebook a useful reference for now:

https://gist.github.com/bryevdv/ff84871fcd843aceea4f0197be9c57e0

Note that that notebook is a proof of concept, you will need a `0.12.4` dev release for it to work, and some of the details of usage may change.